# Issue with importing data into R

Tags: r

I load a file into R . The data goes from negative values to big positive values.
The negative values are imported with " " around them (see below).
$ Value               : Factor w/ 11961 levels "-1.25","-102.34",..: 6541
If I change the type of the data to numeric, I now get a list of values from 1 to 11961 (the number of observations) in that column.

I ran the following script as.numeric(as.character(PMData8$Value)). It shows the data as it as numerics after running it but when I do a str(PMData8) again, I still see the data with " " around some of the data i.e. the negative data. Why is that ?

Comment: Did you run this?  PMData8$Value<-as.numeric(as.character(PMData8$Value))

Comment: Hi there . No only as "as.numeric(as.character(PMData8$Value))". "PMData8$Value<-as.numeric(as.character(PMData8$Value))" does not work. it only shows a + in the next line and nothing is executed.

Comment: Running only "as.numeric(as.character(PMData8$Value))" just outputs the results and does not update the original variable, thus is why one has to reassign "<-" the results back to the original variable.  The + sign most likely means you missed a closing ).